# Updating Site via FTP with weird results

Tags: ftp, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to upload files via FTP to a webserver, but I'm getting really weird results.

I login to the server with no errors.

If I upload a file that already exists on the server, like index.html, the existing file does not get replaced with the updated file (I can tell because the file size is not changing).  I'm using FileZilla and selected the option to overwrite the existing file.

If I upload a new file to the server, the transfer goes through and I can see it on the server in the FileZilla FTP directory listing, but when I try to view the file via http in a web browswer I get a 404 error.

I noticed that on the server, for each and every ASCII file exists an exact duplicate with a .lck extention.  For example, if index.php and categories.php exists on the server, then there also exists index.php.lck and categories.php.lck.  Could this have anything to do with the issue?

The person who used to do do the updates used dreamweaver to create and ftp to the site.  Does dreamweaver put some type of lock on the server?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Dreamweaver creates .lck files to show that a file is checked out. [According to Adobe](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/154/tn_15447.html) the .lck should be deleted when the file is checked back in. Maybe there is an error, or your coworker isn't checking them back in correctly. Have you tried deleting the .lck files?

According to [this site](http://www.mediacollege.com/adobe/dreamweaver/site-management/lck-remove.html), it can be done in one fell swoop:

```
find . -name "*.LCK" -exec rm {} \;
```

(You'll want to try that out somewhere harmless first. It always makes me nervous running an rm command I haven't tested)

Comment: On Unix systems you'll probably want to use `-iname` instead of `-name` for a case-insensitive match.